# In monorepo, Next.js throw compile error when build a pacakge used in Next.js

Tags: next.js, monorepo, pnpm

First, I apologize for the lengthy question. I'm currently experiencing issues while using Next.js in a monorepo. The situation is as follows.

1. For example, in the monorepo, there are two packages: Next.js and `components`. And I'm using Next.js as follows.

```
"dependencies": {
  "components": "workspace:^0.1.0"
}
```

2. And the `components` package uses Vite as its bundler and Sass for providing styles. Below is the `package.json` of the `components` package.

```json
{
  "name": "components",
  "private": false,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

3. And since Next.js and `components` are part of a monorepo environment using pnpm,

- Next.js installs and uses `components`
- running `pnpm run dev` to develop in Next.js
- whenever the `components` package is built, Next.js automatically starts the compilation process.

4. Now, when building the components package, it doesn't always happen, but **sometimes**(approximately one out of every two times) I encounter the following error during compilation:

```
- wait compiling...
error ./src/pages/index.tsx:6:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/dist/styles/index.scss'
  4 | import Head from 'next/head';
  5 | import type { ReactElement } from 'react';
> 6 | import 'components/dist/styles/index.scss';
  7 | 
  8 | import style from './index.module.scss';
  9 | import { NEXT_PUBLIC_ANT_MAN_URL } from '../../appConfig';

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

5. To resolve this issue, it is necessary to rebuild the `components` package instead of refreshing the browser. However, please note that there is a possibility that the problem may occur again even after rebuilding.

How can I resolve this issue? I would appreciate some help, please.

Additionally, when modifying code in Next.js, compilation occurs only once. However, when modifying and building in the `components` package, compilation occurs 2-3 times.